# populate multiple dropdownlists with same data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to populate 12 asp:dropdownlist 's with the same 0-9 options. (ASP.NET VB)

Now I could just populate them manually, but I wandered if there is an easier method... Can i populate an Array and use that to populate them all?

I thought I could write a small function that you pass the DDL's name into, but how then could I use that function input string as the dropdownlist name?

I know this is simple stuff but its something Ive not needed to do before, and cant see a simple method to do it.

Comment: just try and implement your idea. write a function. pass `DropDownlist` as a parameter. or a `List (Of DropDownList)` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then


        BindDropdown(list1)
        BindDropdown(list2)
        BindDropdown(list3)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindDropdown(ByVal list As DrodownList)

        Dim items As String() = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9" }
        list.DataSource = items
        list.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to cache and make a common helper function to bind the dropdown